# Assigning default values to the request object in express js

Tags: node.js, express, connect

How would I go about ensuring that a particular object is available to every request I handle in express?

```
var somethingImportant = "really important";
var app = express();

// This is just a hypothetical example of what I'm after...
app.mixThisInWithRequest({
    somethingImportant: somethingImportant
});

app.use(function (request, response, next) {
   console.log(request.somethingImportant);
});
```

Given the example above, is there a facility akin to the `mixThisInWithRequest` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the `request` object in middleware, as early in the `app.use` chain as you need it:

```
var somethingImportant = "really important";
var app = express();

app.use(function (request, response, next) {
    request.somethingImportant = somethingImportant;
    next();
});
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
   console.log(request.somethingImportant);
});
```

Comment: That occurred to me, I just wanted to make sure brute forcing it with a closure wouldn't hurt things...

Comment: Nothing really brute force about it.  It's the express/connect way.